# Gmail not requiring a response for iCal update

Tags: gmail, icalendar

I am using DDay.iCal to send calendar invites and updates.
Invites and cancels work correctly.
When sending an updated invitation with modified start/end times, Gmail parses the iCal file, and registers that the event has been modified, but does not require a response.

Outlook parses the update correctly and requires a response, but Gmail does not.

I was under the impression that all that is needed to require a response is "PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION" and "RSVP=TRUE"

Below is the update (with email addresses changed of course)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=Test:MAILTO:testemail@gmail.com
DTEND:20150708T154500
DTSTAMP:20150519T155555Z
DTSTART:20150708T150000
LOCATION:Chicago’s Southside EBC - Confucius Room
ORGANIZER;CN=Chicago’s Southside EBC:mailto:testemail2@test.com
SEQUENCE:2
SUMMARY:(1887-4861-1) You are invited to speak at a Briefing with Digital Test Equipment
UID:BEInvite-b6d52388-0a03-4b58-8a47-a4975f1cea83
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Central Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20141102T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=11
TZNAME:Central Standard Time
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20140301T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:Central Daylight Time
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you increase the SEQUENCE property value in your update as well as the DTSTAMP ?

Some extra comments, not necessarily related to your issue:

Your event include a VTIMEZONE component but your DTSTART and DTEND do not reference this VTIMEZONE. You should add a TZID parameter on those properties referencing the TZID of the VTIMEZONE

The VTIMEZONE component is usually placed before the VEVENT in the stream. Did not check whether this is actually mandated by RFC5545 but it is common practice so for interoperability, you should probably move it.